# align text in my menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive site.

I have problems with my menu.
It looks like this when its big:
[image]

and like this when the browser window is smaller:

[image]

how do I style it to make it look like this when its small?

[image]

this is my html

```
<ul id="lg-menu" class="nav">
<li class="active">
    <a href="/Appointment/Uncompleted">

        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i>
        <span class="menuItenText">AVerySuperLong PrettyWord</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="active">
    <a href="/Member">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i>
        <span class="menuItenText">AShort ButPrettyWord</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

EDIT:
js:fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y74K4/

Comment: any CSS we need to know of? Maybe create a fiddle for this...

Comment: Please put your css files.

Comment: no css is needed except bootstrap to demonstrate. Anyway, I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y74K4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this helps you

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/y74K4/1/)

Use `display:table-cell` property to `i` and `span` elements.

CSS

```
.nav{
    display:table;
}

.nav > li{
    display: table-row;
    background-color:blue;
}

.nav li i{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:1.1em;
    color:#fff;
    padding-right:5px;
}
.nav li span{
    display:table-cell;
    color:#fff;
}
```